# Can the Dark Matter / Energy problem be plausibly reframed as an ignorance of gravity problem?

Tags: gravity, dark-matter, dark-energy

I understand Dark Matter was originally proposed to explain the rotation rate of galaxies. The rate was not explained by observed matter, ergo there must be unobserved matter. An alternate explanation would be that the inverse square law is not the whole story over galactic distances.

A similar issue exists for Dark Energy. The universe is expanding faster than predicted by the total matter observed, ergo there must be a lot of energy out there. An alternative explanation would be incomplete  understanding of gravity at intergalactic distances.

Question: Can the Dark Matter / Energy problem be plausibly reframed as an ignorance of gravity problem?

Comment: See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/38908

Comment: This is what I have asked at Physics SE and, perhaps due to my formulation ("dark gravity") it was treated like pseudoscience. But at least some comments mentioned MOND, that is more on the direction of what we are asking,ie a different behaviour of gravity. This would mean that GR as to be improved, besides the famous conflict at quantum scale. Plus 1.

Comment: Thanks. The Wikipedia article on MOND answers my posted question. Apparently cosmologists have been working on this issue for a half century without me.